# Number of light rays which get reflected off an object

Tags: waves, visible-light

I’m in the process of learning Waves and I’ve stumbled upon a question that is beyond me and my understanding.

How many light rays are reflected of an object for us to be able to perceive it?

Basically, what this question is trying to convey is: is there a finite number of rays that an object reflects (for example a blue book would reflect blue visible light waves) or is this number infinite.

Upon first sight, I’d expect there to be an infinite number of rays as if the number was finite, then that would mean that a magnified image would show black spots in between two adjacent light rays.

Disclaimer: This question may be fundamentally wrong or there might be something else wrong with this concept but I am simply curious on how this would work.

Comment: How do you define a single light ray?

Comment: Rays should be thought of as a tool we use to keep track of a particular light path rather than light itself.

Comment: Have you heard of "photons" ? If not, then that's a place to start.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a number of light rays. Light rays are not countable things.

A light ray is a simplification of Maxwell’s equations which is used in geometric optics. It applies when the wavelengths are much smaller than the sizes and distances being analyzed. In that limit the wavefronts (lines of constant phase) of coherent light are particularly simple. A ray is simply a line drawn perpendicular to the wavefronts. You can draw an infinite number of lines perpendicular to any given wavefront.

So while rays are well defined and have good mathematical properties, they are not countable. So it doesn’t make sense to talk about one light ray, nor any other number of light rays.

Comment: Thanks, I realise that this question makes no sense but I kind of expected it. I’m just a secondary school student who was too afraid to ask this to my physics teacher. Also, my teacher never explained light rays as lines drawn perpendicular to the wave front. Thanks for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

Dale's answer is spot on. However, you might find it thought-provoking to know that the minimum amount of light energy that can be transferred through space is called a photon. It is possible in experiments to create light sources so dim that only one photon is emitted at a time. The photons are detected as tiny points of light, so it is possible to build-up an image one photon at a time. As a thought experiment you might imagine having a very feint light source and a detector screen  some distance away. If the light were sufficiently feint (or the screen sufficiently far away) then individual points of light would detected on the screen and there would indeed be dark areas between them.